# Java RMI programming a service

Tags: java, rmi

I am new to java rmi. And I want to create a rmi program as a service. For example, I got a remote interface:

```
public interface Handler implements Remote {
    public void insert (String str) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException;
}

public class HandlerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Handler {
    public HandlerImpl (int port) {
        super(port);
    }

    public void insert (String str) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        // insert string to a file
    }
}
```

And I also have a class to register it:

```
class Server {
    public Server () {
        Registry svcReg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(999);
        Handler handler = new HandlerImpl (1000);
        svcReg.rebind("insert", handler);
    }
}
```

Now if a write the program with

```
Server server = new Server();
```

When the program terminates, the service is gone. What is proper way to make Server like a service that it runs in the background and the "remote method" can still be called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/index.html) to accomplish that.